# how to install new instance of sql server 2012 if i have already installed sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I need an instance of sql server 2012 but i have on my computer already installed sql server 2014. Is it possible to install an instance of sql server 2012 over sql server 2014?

If I try to install sql server 2012 I get an error with the title SQL Server Setup and in the description of the error is a red circle with an X inside and blank text. (Sorry, but I am not allowed to post images yet.)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you looked for any errors in the [Windows event logs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)?

Comment: I managed to install SQL Server 2012. The problem was that I tried to open setup.exe before extracting ISO file. Thank you!